# Virtual Keyboard is Hidden on focusEvent

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt project that runs on a tablet that has a default virtual keyboard on it.

So, I have a `QLineEdit ssoEdit;` on which I installed an event filter.

```cpp
   ssoEdit = new QLineEdit(twoFAPage);
   ssoEdit->setStyleSheet(editStyleSheet);
   ssoEdit->setObjectName("ssoEdit");
   ssoEdit->installEventFilter(this);
```

In the event filter, I have an `if` statement to check for `QEvent::focusIn` and `watchedObject` to be my `lineEdit`. If true, I change the `lineEdit` geometry to move it higher.

```cpp
bool TemplateObject::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event){



    if(event->type()==QEvent::FocusIn && watched->objectName()=="ssoEdit")
    {
        int x,y,w,h;


        ssoLabel->geometry().getRect(&x,&y,&w,&h);
        ssoLabel->setGeometry(QRect(x,y-100,w,h));

        ssoEdit->geometry().getRect(&x,&y,&w,&h);
        ssoEdit->setGeometry(QRect(x,y-100,w,h));



    }



    return false;
}
```

When I press the `ssoEdit`, the event is fired and the `ssoEdit` is moved higher but the virtual keyboard don't show up (although the cursor shows up in the `ssoEdit`). If I press the `ssoEdit` again, the keyboard shows up.

I'm looking for the keyboard to show and stay up when the `ssoEdit` is first pressed and moved up.

I don't know what to try. Is there any way I can force the keyboard to show up? I have to mention I can't use QML files. Just C++.

I will update with code later if necessary.

Comment: I would advice to include some code into your question. I will increase the chances to receiving help plus reduce the chances to have your question flagged and closed.

Comment: To add to acarlstein's comment, please include a [mcve] in your question. Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**.

Comment: I will upload code later today. I dont have access to the code right now

Answer (score 0):

I will close the question as i found a solution. There was a method that returned a pointer to default keyboard and then i could call show() on that pointer. This methods were available on the sdk provided with the project.